# What is the maximum of $x + y + z$ when $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 8$?

Tags: calculus

What is the maximum of $x + y + z$ when $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 8$?

I came across this question today, but cannot get the right answer.

This is how I tried to solve it: 
$$(x + y + z)^2 ≤ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 8 $$
$$x + y + z = \sqrt 8$$

Could someone please tell me where I went wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Lookup the [AM-RMS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) inequality.

Comment: "Could someone please tell me where I went wrong?" 

You went wrong everywhere. The inequality you wrote
$$(x + y + z)^2 \le x^2 + y^2 + z^2 $$
 is wrong for all positive $x,y,z$, and the equality $$x + y + z = \sqrt{8}$$ has nothing to do with the inequality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz, we get:

$(x+y+z)^2 \leq (1+1+1)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

and from here I believe you can work it out.

Also regarding your original inequality that you assumed, a counterexample happens when $(x, y, z) = (2, 2, 0)$, so might be that you either applied Cauchy incorrectly, or you had a wrong conceptual knowledge in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but an illustration of the problem. The curves on the sphere are contours of $x+y+z$. Towards the upper right [in the direction of $(1,1,1)$], the contours have values $\{0,1,2,3,4,4.8\}$.

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 0):

Using Lagrange multipliers i.e. $\vec{\operatorname{grad}}\ g=\lambda\ \vec{\operatorname{grad}}\ f$ where $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-8$ and $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$.

This means $(2x,2y,2z)=\lambda(1,1,1)\iff x=y=z$

From there $3x^2=8$ gives $f(x,x,x)=2\sqrt{6}$

Note that this is easy to visualize geometrically, the plane $x+y+z=cst$ moves along the normal vector $(1,1,1)$ when the $cst$ changes, and the ultimate point of intersection with the sphere is also a tangential point (therefore verifying the Lagrange multiplier equation). So it is the maximum value.